# Regex for no white space at the beginning and at the and and only one in between

Tags: java, regex

I am creating a user input form where a user can enter his name and I want to use a regex for the following pattern:

^[A-Za-z_äÄöÖüÜß_.-]*

It only should accept the above letters, and dots if any and slashes if any.

Moreover I want it to accept white spaces but not at the beginning and not at the end and only one white space between name parts.

E.g. if user's name is **Dora F. T. Kov**
it should be valid.

If I am adding \\s to my regex, it allows any amount of white spaces in my string anywhere.

How could I rewrite it based on the above concept?

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: Do you have to do it all in a single regex?  `input.matches("[A-Za-z_äÄöÖüÜß_.-]*") && input.trim().equals(input)` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
^[A-Za-z_äÄöÖüÜß_.-]+(?: [A-Za-z_äÄöÖüÜß_.-]+)*$
```

[See regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vGReMG/1/)

1. `^` - Matches start of string
2. `[A-Za-z_äÄöÖüÜß_.-]+` Matches one or more of these allowed characters
3. `(?: [A-Za-z_äÄöÖüÜß_.-]+)*` - Followed by 0 or more occurrences of: single space followed by one or more of your allowed characters.
4. `$` - Matches end of string

Answer (score 0):

Try: `^[A-Za-z_äÄöÖüÜß_.-]*(?: [A-Za-z_äÄöÖüÜß_.-]*)*$`

See it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/8VyQew/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Unfortunately, it allows spaces everywhere and any amount.